# How to do screen-size-aware layout?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm making a board game. To construct the board, I do the following:

```
    // adapted from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Reversi-XAMLC-sample-board-816140fa/sourcecode?fileId=69011&pathId=706708707
    // This is shit code.
    async void PlayGame_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var row in Game.ALL_ROWS)
        {
            boardGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(BOARD_GRID_SIDE_LENGTH) });
        }
        var maxColIndex = Game.ALL_ROWS.Max();
        foreach (var col in Enumerable.Range(0, maxColIndex))
        {
            boardGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(BOARD_GRID_SIDE_LENGTH) });
        }

        // ...
     }
```

(Feel free to suggest alternate approaches.)

Basically, I create a bunch of rows and columns based on a pre-set height and width, and fill those rows and columns with board spaces. This works fine when I set the row and column lengths to fit my laptop, but obviously it won't work on devices with different resolutions. (For instance, it's truncated on the Surface RT.) How do I get around this? Can I specify a side length that's a portion of the parent container? What's the best practice here?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would probably be to use a [ViewBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.viewbox), assuming the board you want to draw has a constant number of rows/columns.

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
var bounds = Window.Current.Bounds;

double height = bounds.Height;    
double width = bounds.Width;
```

to find out the screen resolution on which my apps are, and then re-size my grid items on function of the size of the screen.

EDIT:
So for your code I would do:

```
 async void PlayGame_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
             var bounds = Window.Current.Bounds;

             double BOARD_GRID_SIDE_LENGTH = bounds.Height;    
             double BOARD_GRID_SIDE_WIDTH = bounds.Width;

            foreach (var row in Game.ALL_ROWS)
            {
            boardGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(BOARD_GRID_SIDE_LENGTH) });
        }
        var maxColIndex = Game.ALL_ROWS.Max();
        foreach (var col in Enumerable.Range(0, maxColIndex))
        {
            boardGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(BOARD_GRID_SIDE_WIDTH) });
        }

        // ...
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The sound solution is to divide your page so that the `boardGrid` takes 2/3 of the screen, the rest of your content (buttons, timer, score board...) in the other third.

Secondly, enclose it inside a `Viewbox` element so that the board dimensions are recalculated when you go to different view modes (Full, Portrait, Snapped, Filled)

Finally, make sure to make the page inherit `LayoutAwarePage` instead of `Page` so that it handles the changes of view modes gracefully

Here's a rough mockup:

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage
xmlns:UI="using:Microsoft.Advertising.WinRT.UI"
x:Class="ApexKT.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MyApp"
xmlns:common="using:MyApp.Common"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:snaps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2007/xaml/presentation"
mc:Ignorable="d" >    
<Grid x:Name="bigGrid">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel x:Name="OneThird">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ScoreBoard" Text="Score:" />
            <Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Button 1" Click="" />
        </StackPanel>
        <Viewbox x:Name="TwoThirds">
            <Viewbox.Transitions>
                <TransitionCollection>
                    <ContentThemeTransition />
                </TransitionCollection>
            </Viewbox.Transitions>
            <Grid x:Name="boardGrid"><!-- insert row and column definitions here, or hard code them --></Grid>
        </Viewbox>
    </StackPanel>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscape"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="Filled"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="Snapped" />
            <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait" />
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Grid>
```

`